# How data recovery works in flash memory?

Tags: memory, flash

Flash memory is Electronically Erasable Programmable Read Only Memory. In this data is stored by the On or Off state of the transistor. Then How it is possible to recover the data stored in the device even after formatting it ?

Answer (score 3):

Because just like with magnetic media, normal "formatting" does not actually erase the sectors used for file data until the space needs to be reused. Until that happens, it is generally possible to reconstruct most of the data structures that describe the files, which is what data recovery software is doing.

Comment: That means if data in a cell can be recovered only if new data is not written on that particular cell ?

Comment: @tollin: exactly.

Comment: Note, there was a way on old magnetic disks to recover data, when they are truly formatted (by rewriting all tracks). But there was another reason: there was magnetic remanence.

Comment: @Vovanium: But that requires disassembling the drive and connecting the heads to special circuitry that can resolve the small residual values of remanence.

Comment: @DaveTweed floppy disks do not need disassembing but yes, still need special circuitry :)

Comment: in this case noise margin of data will be very poor. So there is very good chance that recovered data is incorrect. ?